# Azure Load Balancer Health Status

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

I've setup a load balancer and health endpoints and would like to see if it's healthy since I'm unable to establish a connection. How can I achieve this in the Azure portal?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-monitor-log

Answer (score 2):

Azure Load Balancer comes in two SKUs.

Standard SKU, public and internal, provides multi-dimensional metrics (including per endpoint health probe status) through Azure Monitor.  http://aka.ms/lbdiags You can consume these metrics in Monitor directly or any of the integrations available with Monitor.

Basic SKU, public only, provides diagnostic logs with per pool health status through Azure Log Analytics diagnostic logs.  Per endpoint health probe status is not exposed in public Basic LB.  Log Analytics diagnostic logs are not supported for internal Basic LB.

Answer (score 1):

For both public and internal standard load balancers, you can see the health probe status through the Azure monitor. For basic public load balancers, you can check health probe status and probe count via log analytics. This is not available for internal basic load balancers.

You can find **Monitoring** in your load balancer panel in the Azure portal. You also get more details from [Log analytics for public Basic Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-monitor-log). You may also want to know the normal or expected [Probe down behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-custom-probe-overview#probedown) and [troubleshooting the Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-troubleshoot).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was really just hoping for a simple status indicator or graph in the portal. I setup diagnostic logging to 'Log Analysis' and don't see any logs. I also looked in 'Azure Monitor' and I can't find a way to select metrics for the load balancer (everything else is present).

Comment: What is the type of your load balancer?